# Tableless ActiveRecord Object with few persistant data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, active-attr

I want tableless AR object. Pseudo code:

```
# tablefull AR object
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :color
end

# tableless AR object, but persistant
class Color
  include ActiveAttr::Model
  belongs_to :item
  attribute :color
  Colors = [:yellow, :red, :black]
end

# expect
Color.first => #<Color id:1, color: :yellow>
Item.create(color: Color.first, foo: 'bar')
Item.where(color_id: Color.first)
```

I look at below so, but these are tableless and not persistant.
[How to create ActiveRecord tableless Model in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123858/how-to-create-activerecord-tableless-model-in-rails-3)
[Ruby on Rails: Fully functional tableless model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997762/ruby-on-rails-fully-functional-tableless-model)

Comment: How could the tableless object be persistant? Where to persist it?

Comment: @xdazz Class or instance variables, I think.

Comment: ```persist``` is not precise, ```load once``` is precise.

Comment: @sanemat Neither class nor instance variables provide persistence, as the term is understood in the Rails community. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using some terms in a non-standard way. When the Rails community (and most technical communities I know of) speaks of "persistence" they mean "saving data somewhere durable". This means, at least, "saving data someplace other than your application's memory" and it usually means "saving data in a way that will survive an application crash (e.g. to disk)." In the case of ActiveRecord, persistence means something very particular -- storage to a SQL database.

So, your example succeeds in getting a "tableless" model. If you want persistence with ActiveRecord, go with a normal (table-backed) model. I realize this may not be the answer you are looking for, but it is what you need to hear.